# What does "[on hold ]" mean?

Tags: discussion

Many questions have this [on hold]. What does it mean?
I have not tried anything.
Yes it is written using proper grammar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the simple answer is clearly explained on the questions that are marked "on hold", in the [help] and in excessive detail on the [main meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Comment: It might be a very simple question, and it might be a question that shows little research, but I don't see how it's off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

It means that no answers can be added to the question - usually happens when the community votes to close the question, which can happen for different reasons (either it is off topic, doesn't make sense, difficult to understand or simply doesn't fit how the system works).

It gives the question author the chance to edit and correct the issues, so the community can reopen the question so someone could answer it.